# HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401}

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, httpresponse, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am new to Angular and ionic. This is my first project. I want to call an API  endpoint from angular and on a valid response i want to switch to next page.

It is not working, i'am getting this error

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "OK", url: "http://api/auth/session", ok: false, …}
```

I have searched almost everything on the internet but could not find any solution. Please help me.

Code :

For my Login File :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DashboardPage } from '../dashboard/dashboard';
import { AuthProvider } from '../../providers/auth/auth';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
      public loadingController: LoadingController,
      public authService: AuthProvider,
      public storage: Storage) {

  }

  auth() {

  }

  dashboard() {

    this.authService.loginUser("test1", "1234").subscribe((result) =>{
      console.log(`result :: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);

      if(result.sessionToken){
        this.set('token', result.sessionToken);
    }
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage)

  }) 
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
    this.auth();
  }

  public set(settingName, value){
      return this.storage.set(`setting:${ settingName }`,value);
  }

  async presentLoading() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      duration: 2000
    });
    return await loading.present();
  }

}
```

**auth.js**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello AuthProvider Provider');
  }

  loginUser (email : string, password : string) : Observable <any> {
    const headers = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    }
    return this.http.post <any> ('http://api/auth/session',{
        "username": email,
        "password":password
    }, headers);
  }

}
```

This is all my code. Please help.

Comment: Please install cors plugin for chrome and enable it.This with avoid cross origin error if you are pointing to server at different location.

Comment: but this is not cors error. This is "missingAuthorization" error. @AndrewRayan

Comment: @AndrewRayan, I am doing this for mobile device

Comment: @mishti this is an error thrown by api which can be `catched`.

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#error-handling

Comment: I would suggest first making sure your request works in a tool like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) or curl. Make sure `username` and `password` are the right parameter names for your service.

Comment: what backend you are using?

Comment: As  abadalyan's point please check your request with postman.If it works then you have to handle in server.

Comment: @AndrewRayan it is working fine with postman

Comment: Then cors has to be added in server side.What language are you using for server side?

Comment: We are using angular and cors have been added @AndrewRayan